# MOXy 2.5.1 dependency on JavaEE causes NoClassDefFoundError in JavaSE

Tags: eclipselink, moxy

The MOXy class org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLBinaryDataHelper uses the JavaEE class javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.  Because of this, an error is thrown if the code is running with JavaSE.

Is this dependency on JavaEE intentional?  I have not seen any documentation which states that you cannot use JavaSE.

Including a Maven dependency to javax.mail:javax.mail-api:1.5.1 eliminates the error but seems rather hackish considering my code doesn't actually use anything in that JAR.

Comment: Can you post the part of your domain model that holds on to the binary data?  I am attempting to reproduce the error you are seeing.

Comment: Hello @BlaiseDoughan, I do have the same problem, after adding XmlInlineBinaryData to a variable, I had to add de javax.mail-api dependency. Do you need a small example to verfiy the problem?

Comment: If you can post an example that would be a big help.